# what is the difference between atomicity and durability in DBMS?

Tags: oracle, database

the difference between atomicity and durability of DBMS is somewhat vague so i am asking for a clear difference between the two ?

Comment: Please perform cursory research. The [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) Wikipedia entry is fairly clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are two of the four ACID properties, which allow for reliability of database transactions.

Simplistically, atomicity means that something either happens or doesn't happen - there is no halfway state.

For example, when I transfer money between accounts at my bank, there's no possibility the money will leave one account without showing up in the other. For example, you may find something like:

```
start transaction
  update working_account set balance = balance - 100
  update savings_account set balance = balance + 100
commit transaction
```

At the commit point, atomicity guarantees that either both `update` statements happen or neither of them do (if there's an error of some sort, or if you roll back the transaction rather than committing it).

---

On the other hand, durability means that, once it's happened, it *stays* happened.

That means the bank won't forget that I transferred the money.

In the context of the above statements, the `commit` *remembers* what has been done (on non-volatile memory, on disk, or otherwise) so that catastrophic failure will not affect the transaction.